# Can I use a Doorbell 24v transformer as a C-Wire transformer?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, doorbell, 24v-transformer

Can I use my currently working 1970s doorbell 24v transformer as a C-Wire transformer? I'm installing a Honeywell Home Wi-Fi 7-Day Programmable Thermostat (RTH6580WF), Requires C Wire.

I ordered a LIANSUM 24V 500mA C Wire Adapter for Thermostat and Doorbell Transformer, Compatible with Nest, Ecobee, Sensi, Honeywell, Sensi Smart WiFi Thermostat, Nest from Amazon, JIC.

Comment: How about explaining a little more about the exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You can also use the furnace transformer as a C-wire transformer.  So why do something different?

Comment: Your furnace will come on every time someone rings your doorbell.

Comment: The furnace transformer isn't always rated to provide enough current to run (for example) a smart thermostat on each of two zones. Depends on the thermostat, depends on the furnace circuitry. When it isn't, using another 24V transformer to provide that power is the solution recommended by the makers of those.

Comment: @keshlam you could write that as answer so it can be discussed to the benefit of the OP and other readers

Answer (score 0):

That would not work

The R- 24 V hot and the C- common have to be a part of same closed loop circuit (same transformer)

So if you want to use the door bell transformer then you have use both (the R and the C) for it

Comment: ... I presumed that was the intent. But you're right, it wasn't stated clearly if so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In terms of voltage, the two are 24V AC and thus the doorbell transformer can be used as a thermostat C-wire transformer.

The C-wire transformers I found can supply about 300mA, and doorbell transformers can feed more, about 1A.

Since you already have the doorbell transformer and have it wired in, use it. Someone who does not have it should get the thermostat one, since it is plug-in and cheaper.

If the cable from furnace to thermostat has enough wires you could use the furnace power supply. But often the inadequate wire or fear of opening the furnace is the reason people get the separate supply.

This is perhaps obvious, but the transformer has no polarity (it's AC) and make sure you wire both leads from the transformer to the appropriate terminals (R/C) of the thermostat.